# How to attach JavaScript and Bootstrap files to Codeigniter Project

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am having problems working with JavaScript and bootstrap files.

- Where to attach the JavaScript files? In header or in footer?
- Where to attach the bootstrap files? In header or in footer?
- Is it Ok to use CDNs or we should use files in project?
- There are .js files in bootstrap folder. Are they different than other JavaScript files. That is, is it ok to attach the bootstrap file only and not the other proper JavaScript file?

Answer (score 1):

Create two folders in assets folder if not exists already.

1. CSS
2. JS

Place your bootstrap CSS files in CSS folder and jquery JS files in JS folder. I think you have already configured your `site_url()` after that simply link files in header like this.

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/css/jquery-ui.css">
```

You can also use CDN links if you do not want to setup. But you will not be able to access them if you have no internet connection. I hope it helps.